# Relational database relations for welded seams

Tags: database, jboss-weld

I am building a database application for taking care of welded seams.  Welds connects different parts ( pipes, plates with different dimensions ) which are different materials ( steel alloys ).  Also the number of welds is part of the problem.

[image: Relations]

There might be a room for improvements.

Comment: Are you wedded to Access, or would you consider switching to another RDBMS with more expressive data-modelling capabilities (like Postgres)?

Comment: What is the precise question? This site probably doesn't have many welding experts. Also, I don't understand the language/terms used in your diagram which makes it impossible to assist anyway.

Comment: I can't really help you as I don't understand your model because I don't speak Finnish - can you please provide an English translation?

Comment: To generate a data model, we'd need a lot more info. I can't make out the wriiting on your current model. But really it's all about identifying the entities and the types of relationships between them